# Saving dynamically generated inputs grid with the same ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these snippets of code :

```js
$scope.createPack = function(informationsPack, informationsActivite) {
            PackService.add(informationsPack, informationsActivite)
                .then(function(res) {
                    $state.go('packs.list');
                }, function(error) {
                    alert('error : ' + error);
                })

        };
```

```html
 <form name="packAddForm" id="packAddForm" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                        Jour {{ item.jour }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" id="nom_activite" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Activité"
                                        ng-model="informationsActivite.name_activity">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <textarea name="description_activite" id="description_activite" cols="60"
                                          rows="5" ng-model="informationsActivite.description_activity"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal"
                        ng-click="createPack(informationsPack, informationsActivite)">
                    Enregistrer</button>
```

What I'm trying basically to do is generating 1, 2 or 3 input based on what the user gave. And that is what the **ng-repeat** is doing. But the problem is when I submit the form how can I get all the values of the generated inputs. If it was just one input it would be ok. But for example if I have 2 **informationsActivite.name_activity** generated how can I get all datas. I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this

```
<div>
    <textarea name="description_activite{{$index}}"
        id="description_activite{{$index}}" cols="60" rows="5"
        ng-model="informationsActivite.description_activity{{$index}}"></textarea>
</div>
```

to make these attribute values unique.

*Side note- duplicate id attributes in a html document makes it invalid*

Comment: Merci de ton aide koolunix. Et après on niveau des services http comment transmettre à la base de données en post ?

Comment: Utilisez le NG-soumettre la directive dans l'élément de formulaire à poster dans la base de données. Jetez un coup d'oeil à ceci : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form